# Django: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd1 in position 2: invalid continuation byte

Tags: python, mysql, django

I'm new in Django so I got stuck. I'm having troubles with Django and MySQL connection. Instead of Cyrillic characters I got a bunch of strange symbols, but I'm using utf8_unicode_ci as character and collation in MySQL for database and tables. How can I solve this problem?

This is the error I'm getting:

[image]

This is what I got in MySQL:

[image]

settings.py file:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'some_name',
        'HOST': 'some_host',
        'PORT': 3306,
        'USER': 'some_user',
        'PASSWORD': 'some_password',
    }
}
```

Comment: We should have a look at your code to identify the reason. Can you please provide the specific part of your code responsible for the connection?

Comment: Do you mean the part of settings.py file? If so, I edited my answer.